# Installation of mysql-server crashed, can't reinstall

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, apt

I tried to install the `mysql-server` package on my Ubuntu VPS. The `apt-get` process crashed and I had to kill it. Now I have this error message whenever I try to install it again:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6,452 B of archives.
After this operation, 98.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server.
(Reading database ... 36812 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.10.1_all.deb) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.1 (5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up man-db (2.6.0.2-2) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing man-db (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libapache2-mod-php5 (5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6) ...
    debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up php5-cli (5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing php5-cli (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.1; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.1
 man-db
 libapache2-mod-php5
 php5-cli
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help, it's kind of urgend.

Comment: first you have to uninstall the mysql server from mysql removal tool on ubuntu and then again install it in your system. you can find the mysql removal tool from net

Comment: Can you point me to it, I seem to be too incompetent to find it.

Comment: Because you are installing from net, than may your net be disconnected or the mysql package be corrupted and happen more thing to break this. I hope this link help you http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1407998

Comment: if the package was corrupted, dpkg wouldn't be trying to install it, since the md5sum would not match what is in the Packages file.

Comment: @GhostAnswer your second comment helped me a bit. Mysql won't start anyway, so I have to find some other way.

Answer (score 0):

run `fuser /var/cache/debconf/config.dat` to find the process which locked that file. (you might have to install the psmisc package to get fuser).  I'd try to kill that process (but gracefully, not with -9)

Comment: The file seems not to be use outside of the process. `fuser` does not tell me anything. Only when I start the `apt-get`, I get the error that it's locked.